# How do I hoogle for ordered/sorted data structures?

Tags: sorting, haskell, data-structures

I'm looking for data structures that require their members to be instances of `Ord`, and I'm having trouble finding any on Hackage. I've searched on [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Ord%20a%20%3D%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20f%20a) and [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/lts-18.5/hoogle?q=Ord%20a%20%3D%3E%20a%20-%3E%20f%20a%20-%3E%20f%20a) for the expression `Ord a => [a] -> f a`, because I would expect something like `fromList`. Why am I not finding anything?

[Here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/heaps-0.4/docs/Data-Heap.html#g:5) is an example of the type of function/data structure I'd like to find.

Comment: Hm, really strange that [`Data.Set.fromList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Set.html#v:fromList) doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2):

There is a strong naming convention in the Haskell world, so I would recommend Hoogling for [`singleton`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=singleton) and [`fromList`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=fromList). Results won't be restricted to things that require `Ord`, but from a cursory glance it does look like those results achieve pretty good coverage.

It doesn't look like Hoogle has a convenient way to ask for more results, but you can click on the `-` sign next to package names on the left to filter out packages you've already triaged as being unrelated to your interests, and results from other packages will fill in at the bottom.

Comment: Looking for `member` and `lookup` might be helpful too, and those won't be as littered with sequences.